# How to change psql default listening host?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, port, postgresql

I've installed postgresql 8.3 manually on ubuntu 10.10, using ./configure, make and make install.

It works perfect but when I try to connect it using psql I need to type following cmd,
`psql --port --host localhost`,  my question is, Is there a way that I can omit `--host=localhost` paramter ??

Error Details when passing only port and not passing `--host` parameter

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5431"?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an alias for psql?

`alias psql="psql --host localhost"`

Alternatively you could set the PGHOST environment variable.

Comment: It may work but its not concrete solution, I want to know something solid like what's default value of --host and from which config. file I can alter the host name.

Comment: Psql does read ~/.psqlrc on startup, but it looks like you can only use it to configure the connection, not the login itself...

Comment: There's PGHOST too.. Modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

Um, that syntax isn't correct to start:  there is nothing being passed to --port.  Locally, I get the exact message:
`% psql --port --host=localhost
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.0"?`

Passing a port (and omitting the --host) should work:
`% psql --port 5432
Welcome to psql 8.3.8, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.`

Defining PGDATA, PGHOME, and PGPORT should help with not having to pass arguments to psql.